# jQuery clone div with replaced values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="multipleSteps">
    <div id="step_1">
        <input type="text" name="step_name_1" id="step_name_1">
    </div>
</div>
```

A simple clone works but I have no idea about how can I clone it and replace "_1" with "_2".

Here is what I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
var newStep = $( "#step_1" );
newStep = text.replace("_1", "_2");
newStep.prependTo( "#multipleSteps" );
```

Comment: FYI - You can use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()` like `text.replaceAll("_1", "_2");`. Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to get the html of `step_1` as a text then replace `"_1"` by `"_2"` and then append the new html to `multipleSteps` div :

```
var html = $("#step_1").prop('outerHTML').replace(/_1/g, '_2')
var newStep = $(html);
newStep.appendTo("#multipleSteps");
```

`prop('outerHTML')` is used to get the html of an element including it self

`replace(/_1/g, '_2')` is used to replace all `"_1"`

https://jsfiddle.net/ao92wrtz/

Answer (score 2):

Using this code your id step "step_1" counter is set dynamicaly.

```js
var newStep = $( "#step_1" ).prop('outerHTML');
count = $('#multipleSteps').length;
newStep = newStep.replace("_1", "_"+(count+1));
$(newStep).appendTo("#multipleSteps");
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multipleSteps">
    <div id="step_1">
        <input type="text" name="step_name_1" id="step_name_1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnak you. The only issue remaining is that "replace" is not working. Keeps the "step_1" and the "step_name_1" in the second div. Any idea about how can I fix this?

Lated edit: replace(/_1/g, '_2') is used to replace all "_1" is the solution.